# jQuery: get the selected text as comma separated from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="testID" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">test Value1</option>
   <option value="2">test Value2</option>
   <option value="3">test Value3</option>
   <option value="4">test Value4</option>
   <option value="5">test Value5</option>
  <option value="6">test Value6</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Get dropdown selected Value" id ="select-values">
```

i want to get the comma separated selected text.

I tried ,

```
 $("#select-values").click(function () {
     $("select option:selected").text();
});
```

lets say i have selected first two select options
but i am getting the value `test Value1test Value2`

i want it to be `test Value1,test Value2`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3uFxB/)</kbd>

```
$("#select-values").click(function () {
    var option_all = $("select option:selected").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(',');
    console.log(option_all);
});
```

Comment: have you defined correct the variable `var option option_all =`?

Comment: @jogesh_pi sorry was a typo . added demo also check

Comment: cool.. works great, +1, just For my info, can you select the values on click of the button so that they get displayed individually on click without selecting them to be displayed? - @TusharGupta

Comment: @NathanLee i didn't understand what you asking for ?

Comment: When you press on 'Get dropdown selected Value' button, the values from each box, should print on the next line without selecting them to be printed and each print should be in a uniform order, for instance, when you click the 'Get dropdown selected Value' button, test Value1,test Value2, etc should get printed individually on the next line on each click. Is that possible? - @TusharGupta

Comment: Yes, but instead of selecting them, it should print one after the other on the next line on clicks like in your first solution. - @TusharGupta

Comment: No.. Thats the same as your first solution.. No worries, I shall figure out myself.. thx - @TusharGupta

Comment: @NathanLee i'm not able to understand you sorry :(

Comment: ok, let me put it this way.. when you press on the button, nothing happens, when you select something and then press again, that selected value gets printed on the next line. I want to print values from top to bottom just on click of the button without selecting them. Does that clear the picture? - @TusharGupta

Comment: +1, only thing i'd change is that there is no real need to create a jquery object for each item just to get the text

Comment: 1up from me. Thanks For the answer. Can You Please tell me what should we do when we ideally edit this selected value in the edit part.

Answer (score 5):

This feels like the quickest way:

```
$('#testID').val().toString()
```

I'm too lazy to write a for loop for this

Comment: works grea! as you can use the already cached values in case you fetched them before, but will only work when the option text and the values are the same!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

var selectedItems = ($.map($("select[id*=select-values] option:selected"), function(item, i) {
 return $(item).text() })).join(", ");

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select-values").click(function () {
        var val = [];
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            val.push(this.text);
        });
        alert(val.join(','));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you know when you want to get a **value** of a multiple select box, it does this automatically? ^^

Just change the value of your selections:

```
<select id="testID" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="test Value1">test Value1</option>
   <option value="test Value2">test Value2</option>
   <option value="test Value3">test Value3</option>
   <option value="test Value4">test Value4</option>
   <option value="test Value5">test Value5</option>
  <option value="test Value6">test Value6</option>
</select>
```

Then you can call the value with:

```
$('#testID').val();
```

It will automatically seperate the values with a comma.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKyH8/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#select-values").click(function () {
    var select = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function(){
        select += ","+$(this).text();
    });
    if(select != ""){
        select = select.substr(1);
    }
    $("#selection").text(select);
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6233/1)

Comment: Strange. What happens on my end is that when I select a value and press the button, nothing happens, what TusharGupta solution does, is that when I select the value and press the button, it shows me the same value printed on the next line. Are your solutions different? - @Hiral

Comment: Dont know. did you check whole console? it might be printed on first line

Comment: Yes. I checked whole and in your solution, nothing gets displayed. Even solution by Nkmol shows an alert indicating the selection of values. - @Hiral

Comment: It was working but did not print values. just consoled. I think you did not check console log.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple

```
$('#testID').val().join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Selected answer is very good. I made and use this function with $.fn for multiple purposes, you can extract text, val or data from jquery objects:

```
$.fn.QJoin = function(from, glue){

    glue = glue || ',';
    let aText = [];
    for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){

        if( from=='text' ){ aText.push(this.eq(i).text()); }
        else if( from=='val' ){ aText.push(this.eq(i).val()); }
        else if( from.split('-')[0]=='data' ){ aText.push(this.eq(i).data(from.split('-')[1])); }

    }

    return aText.join(glue);
};
```